# EclipseFP not working at all

Tags: eclipse, haskell, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed Haskell and EclipseFP on my computer, using the instructions [here](http://eclipsefp.github.io/install.html). I got as far as installing the plugin.

Unfortunately, the plugin appears to have an internal problem and is outputting the following error when I start Eclipse (as seen in "Error Log").

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_20
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product -data <PATH TO WORKSPACE> -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.equinox.registry
Error
Thu Apr 16 19:37:20 PDT 2015
Plug-in net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui was unable to load class net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.decorators.ProblemsLabelDecorator.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui (339).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition$1.run(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.internalGetDecorator(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.HaskellUIPlugin.start() of bundle net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:936)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.internal.backend.BackendManager.getToolSandbox(BackendManager.java:1108)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.internal.backend.BackendManager.getToolSandboxBin(BackendManager.java:1124)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.internal.backend.BackendManager.getExecutablePath(BackendManager.java:128)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.internal.backend.BackendManager.start(BackendManager.java:175)
    at net.sf.eclipsefp.haskell.ui.HaskellUIPlugin.start(HaskellUIPlugin.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 35 more
```

Is there anything I should do to fix this problem? Or is it just a compatibility issue.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/eclipsefp/issues/269) says you must install Cabal

Comment: @greg-449 If you turn that into an answer, I will give you the accept. Your answer did get me past the "not working at all" problem but it would be nice if you also included the fact that running as administrator (on Windows) seems to get it completely functional.

Comment: It sounds like it would be better if you wrote a self answer. I don't actually know much about this!

Comment: [**It is not maintained anymore**](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.ca/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html) and doesn't seem to work with recent versions.

Comment: @Kaveh thanks, I've switched to ide Haskell for atom

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell and write `cabal --help` and see if it shows you some commands. Else download the [Haskell Platform](https://www.haskell.org/platform/). If you are in Windows make sure you open always your eclipse as administrator:

1. Right click the link to Eclipse
2. Go to the **Compatibility** tab and mark something like **Run always as administrator**
3. Open Eclipse and goto `New/Other/Haskel/` and pick your wanted kind of project.

Comment: When `EclipseFP` is installed before the settings to run `Eclipse` as an administrator, the plugin gets disabled and options for creating a new `Haskell` project disappear. Reinstall `EclipseFP` if you run into that...

Comment: In case you are using MacPorts: EclipseFP cannot find `cabal` because it is installed in `/opt/local/bin`. My solution was to run Eclipse from the shell rather than the UI launcher, e.g. `'/Applications/Eclipse Mars.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse'`. Remember that when you launch an application from Finder your `.bashrc` etc. don't get executed.

Comment: Sure, you can detach it from the console, and will be basically the same experience.